# Is feedback control fundamentally efficient than open-loop control?

Tags: control

Is feedback control more efficient in principle than open-loop control? Is there a name for the principle? (I'd like to do an internet search to understand that theorem.)

Under ideal conditions, ignoring the power and processing time required for feedback, intuitively it seems obvious that feedback control is always more efficient than open loop control.

I believe this has been established with mathematical rigor in control theory as a key principle, but have not been able to find it in any textbooks I have.

I am new to control theory, so apologies if this is a silly question.

**Update**

I think of efficiency in terms of the following problem. (See also figure)

**Concrete problem setting**

Gas particles are enclosed with probability 0.5 on the left or right side of a rigid box (like a cylinder) separated by a movable wall. There are two destinations to move the center wall, the right and left side edges of the box.

If you move the center wall toward the correct direction, you can get the energy out of this box. However, in the wrong direction, you will lose the energy.

We consider two types of controllers, feedback and open-loop controller. Both of the controllers can move the wall to the destinations. So, it is not necessary to observe the states after starting moving wall.

A feedback controller observes **only the initial state** of the box to know which direction the gas particles are enclosed (the left or right side in the box). Thus, the feedback controller knows which direction is appropriate to extract the energy from the box.

An open-loop controller does not observe the state of the box.

We assume that the box and wall works as an ideal engine often appeared in thermodynamics. So the controller can move the wall very smoothly (quasi-statistically) **without feedback**.

We can summarize our setting as followings:

[image]

**Efficiency**

We now define efficiency $\eta$ by the following equation:

$$\eta = \frac{\text{Increase in potential energy of the weight}}{\text{energy consumption during the control}}$$

Because the initial and final state of the weight is the same in any case, the numerator above is constant.

The fuels used can be different because the pressure from the gas is available to lift up the weight by moving the right direction.

Since a feedback controller can know the right direction by its observation, she moves the wall toward the right direction. Then the fuel is zero in our ideal setting.

Meanwhile, becuase a open-loop controller do not know which direction is appropriate, the fuel is necessary to lift up the weight.

Therefore, the efficiency $\eta$ for the feedback controller is greater than one for the open-loop controller in principle.

**FB control is more efficient in principle?**

But, this inference is not rigorous because there might be some tricky methods that allows the open-loop controller to lift up the weight with zero-fuel. (I could not find it, though)

**My question is that whether there is the theory that confirms that there is no such tricky strategy in general and justifies our intuition.**

Comment: I don't think there's any comparison, because you're not able to guarantee an output with open loop control. It's kind of like asking if it's more efficient to run a mile with a GPS versus without - how good are you at guessing how far you've run?

Comment: How do you define "efficient" on this comparison?

Comment: @Chuck Thank you! If you add a GPS, you can choose the shortest distance, so you will have less fuel to reach your destination?

Comment: @AlbertHM Thanks for comment! I updated the question.

Comment: I read the update and disagree with the premise for this question. If you have two vehicles, both pointed at a wall, and have them drive to a target location, only the one with appropriate feedback will move out from behind the wall. The other one will spin tires until it believes itself to be at the target. You can measure "efficiency" by how by fuel was used to get to the target, but the one without feedback never got there, so it's zero? Undefined? Similarly, your setup with "knowing which direction to move" has nothing to do really with the controller and everything to do with the setup.

Comment: Again - there's not really any way to compare efficiency here because the robot isn't going to the same place. Your comment in the post about the "robot moves the wall to the wrong direction" reiterates this. You can't compare efficiency and get any meaning out of the term if you're not comparing the same process.

Comment: @Chuck First of all, thank you again for your useful comments. I am slowly beginning to understand the ideas in control theory. I apologize for the critical lack of my previous premise. The feedback controller observes only once to find out which side of the box the gas is in. In addition, both controllers can move the wall without error. I updated the question again.

Comment: Hm interesting cases. But controller designer should know how actuator affect the system when designing controller. And if controller only look once at the beginning, I'm pretty sure its not feedback controller but it is open loop controller with system analyzer to analyze what actuator do. Close-loop controller would observe state of the system until the end of the process.

Comment: @AlbertHM Thanks for the comment! I believe that, at least in the context of Maxwell demons, a controller who observes only the first time is also a feedback controller. See for example the following paper: Sagawa, T., & Ueda, M. (2012). Nonequilibrium thermodynamics of feedback control. Physical Review E, 85(2), 021104.

Comment: I also do not think this comparison can be done. The closed loop controller controls the trajectory fro the initial to the target state. It can be tuned/optimized for speed, for efficiency for any other arbitrary objective. The open loop trajectory depends only on the system dynamics (and obviously the excitation). To add further to the discussion open loop is in many cases used complimentary to closed loop. The trajectory planning of a robot is done in open loop, but the execution is done in closed loop.

Comment: Also the statement that the open loop controller does not know which way to move is questionable. It is open loop but why would it not be informed about the task?

Comment: The open loop controller can be a model based controller with an absolute perfect model of the system (possible only in theory). That open loop controller would perform exactly the same as the closed loop controller.

Comment: @50k4 Thank you for your valuable comments. I apologize for my misleading explanation. The purpose of the feedback control is to know the proper direction to move the wall with less fuel. This can be found by observing whether the gas is initially in the left or right side. On the other hand, as is often assumed in thermodynamics, we assume that a robot can move the wall smoothly without using feedback. In other words, open-loop control can make the wall move very smoothly to its destination.

Comment: @50k4 We assume that the initial state of the box is uncertain. That is, the robot does not know whether the gas particles are in the left or right side of the box.This uncertainty can be caused by the robot's ignorance of events prior to the initial state. For example, suppose the experimenter randomly encloses the gas in either the left or right side of the box. If the robot does not see the experimenter's action, then the initial state of the box is uncertain for the robot.

Comment: @50k4 In our problem setting, open-loop control and feedback control are equivalent for the action of moving the wall itself. This is because the box and the wall are ideal, as often assumed in thermodynamics, as mentioned above. The questions and figures have been updated to reflect these replies. Thank you very much again.

Comment: You are talking about efficiency and being able to get work "out of the box". But you do not appear to be accounting for the work of moving the piston position, which requires power input even for an "ideal" setting. Your definition of open and closed loop control do not define the control laws but are simply stating if you have knowlege of the system or not.

Comment: In general I would define both of your stated systems as open loop. An open loop controller would be. "move the piston to this location"  A closed loop controller would need continuous feedback "move the piston to the location such that the pressure inside equalizes to X psi".  The continuous feedback is the definition of a closed loop.